# pivot_wider a dataframe with complex names R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidy

so I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
datInput <- tibble(id = 1:2,
             c.0.opt = c("a,b", "c,d"),
             c.0.optI = c("1,2", "3,4"),
             c.0.sel = c("a", "c"),
             c.1.opt = c("e,f", "g,h"),
             c.1.optI = c("5,6", "7,8"),
             c.1.sel = c("e", "g"))

datInput
#     id c.0.opt c.0.optI c.0.sel c.1.opt c.1.optI c.1.sel
 
#1     1 a,b     1,2      a       e,f     5,6      e      
#2     2 c,d     3,4      c       g,h     7,8      g
```

And I need it to look like this:

```
datOutput <- tibble(id = c(1,1,2,2),
                   c_opt = c("a,b", "e,f", "c,d", "g,h"),
                   c_optI = c("1,2", "5,6", "3,4", "7,8"),
                   c_sel = c("a", "e", "c", "g"))

#     id c_opt c_optI c_sel

#1     1 a,b   1,2    a    
#2     1 e,f   5,6    e    
#3     2 c,d   3,4    c    
#4     2 g,h   7,8    g
```

I usually use `dplyr::pivot_longer` for this kind of tasks, but I don't know how to do it with those complicated column names, were the row identifier is in the middle. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datInput %>% 
  gather(colname, val,-1 ) %>% 
  mutate(colname = gsub("\\.\\d\\.","_",colname)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = colname, values_from = val, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(colnames(.)))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
     id c_opt c_optI c_sel
  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1     1 a,b   1,2    a    
2     1 e,f   5,6    e    
3     2 c,d   3,4    c    
4     2 g,h   7,8    g
```

Comment: You can add `values_fn = list` to the pivot to suppress that warning. `gather` has been superseded so you should replace it with `pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "colname", values_to = "val")`.

Comment: Thank you all! This was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 4):

We can use `pivot_longer` as well with `names_sep` as regex lookaround to match the `.` in column names that succeeds a digit

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
pivot_longer(datInput, cols = -id, names_to = c("grp", ".value"), 
         names_sep = "(?<=\\d)\\.") %>%
    select(-grp) %>%
    rename_with(~ str_c('c_', .), -id)
 # A tibble: 4 x 4
 #   id c_opt c_optI c_sel
 #  <int> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
#1     1 a,b   1,2    a    
#2     1 e,f   5,6    e    
#3     2 c,d   3,4    c    
#4     2 g,h   7,8    g
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified Akrun's answer with comments from zimia like this:

```
datOutput <- datInput %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id, names_to = "colname", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(colname = gsub("\\.\\d\\.","_",colname)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = id, names_from = colname, values_from = val, values_fn = list) %>% 
  unnest(cols = c(colnames(.)))
```

It works perfectly. Thank you both.